# Difference sending a File and a byte[] in an MultipartFormEntity

Tags: java, spring, http

I have a Apache HttpComponents HttpClient (v 4.3.5) sending a file to a Spring Boot (v 3.2.1) RestController.

I tried two ways, both using a MultipartFormEntity.

```
var fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(path));
HttpEntity multipartByteArr = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addBinaryBody("content", fileBytes)
        .build();

var file = new File(path);
HttpEntity multipartFile = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addBinaryBody("content", file)
        .build();
```

On the server side, I have two methods, one for each entity.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("byteArr")
    public void byteArr(@RequestParam("content") byte[] fileBytes) {
        System.out.println(fileBytes.length);
    }

    @PostMapping("multipart")
    public void multipart(@RequestParam("content") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(file.getBytes().length);
    }
}
```

On the file request, I get the correct number of bytes in the server. But, for the byte[] request, I get another length.

I would like to understand why.

I tried putting two other parameters on the byteArr entity, (ContentType.BINARY_FILE, "filename.bin"), and it worked on the "multipart" endpoint. I could not make the "byteArr" endpoint receive the correct byte[].

The file has 298254 bytes (and the server printed it correctly on `System.out.println(file.getBytes().length)`)

The byte[] arrived with 347739 bytes.

Comment: What application server?

Comment: The spring-boot-starter-web default embedded tomcat.

Comment: I think the encodings differ. I think the correct-way recieves UTF16 and store the file in UTF8. The wrong way store the genuine UTF16 data. Another reason might be that the file is a 7-bit-byte but this is anicent magic. I came across the 7-bit-byte because 8/7 is 1.14 and the almost same factor for the length difference of the files.